# How do I start an OS X user interface with a button with focus?

Tags: xcode, macos, interface-builder

I have an intermittent problem that is driving me crazy. I have an OS X app in Xcode that has a simple user interface with a button and a few text fields.

Sometimes it starts **with the focus on the button**, which is the behavior I'm seeking, as I have the button mapped to the carriage return key in IB.

But sometimes it starts **without the focus on the button**, and then the carriage return key doesn't work as a button press.

I've tried to set the button as first responder in `init()` with `self.buttonName.becomeFirstResponder()` but that doesn't seem to make much difference as to when the app comes up with the button highlighted and ready to accept a carriage return or not.

I feel like an idiot, as I've been working on this seemingly simple problem for over a week now. Does anybody have any ideas?

@Meriw suggests that I put the first responder call into viewWillAppear. I have in AppDelegate.swift:

```
@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    var mainWindowController: MainWindowController?

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching( aNotification: NSNotification ) {

        // Create a window controller
        let mainWindowController = MainWindowController()

        // Put the window of the window controller on screen
        mainWindowController.showWindow( self )

        // Set the property to point to the window controller
        self.mainWindowController = mainWindowController
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate( aNotification: NSNotification ) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }

    // Make the program disappear after the window is closed
    func applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed( sender: NSApplication ) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

}
```

And in MainWindowController.swift:

```
import Cocoa

class MainWindowController: NSWindowController {

    init() {
        super.init( window: nil )

        // load the contents of the nib, and set the owner as self, which connects the oultlets
        NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed( windowNibName, owner: self, topLevelObjects: nil )
    }

    required init?( coder: NSCoder ) {
        super.init( coder: coder )
    }

    override var windowNibName: String {
        return "MainWindowController"
    }
```

...

Where would viewWillAppear be implemented and how?

Comment: Did you try adding `self.buttonName.becomeFirstResponder()` to `viewWillAppear` instead of `init`? I'd guess your solution doesn't work because the view hasn't finished loading yet in the init method.

Comment: @Meriw Is viewWillAppear prototyped in NS for an OSX app? I don't see it. I have applicationDidFinishLaunching, and I tried putting it there. In fact, over the past week, I've tried putting it just about everywhere :)

Comment: If you are using an NSViewController, viewWillAppear should be available starting from 10.10, according to [this doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSViewController_Class/). In which class are you adding your code?

Comment: @Meriw--you're right! But I'm not sure how to implement it, so I posted the code...

Comment: Hmm, I forgot NSWindowController is usually used for OS X. Try creating the method `windowDidLoad` and put it after a call to `super.windowDidLoad()`

Comment: @Meriw--thanks, but sadly it doesn't seem to work. I tried putting the becomeFirstResponder call in a variety of places as well with that code in place :) The really strange thing is that if I click something on and off in IB, it starts with the focus on the button as it should. I've tried cleaning, etc. before building, but that clicking on and off something in IB *seems to* (I could be hallucinating at this point) fix it for a while. I wonder if I've found a bug in Xcode?

Comment: Wait - is your window focused when it opens? If it isn't, setting the button as the first responder won't work. Also, try using this:
`if buttonName.acceptsFirstResponder { self.view.window.makeFirstResponder(buttonName) }` (from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31867098/how-to-set-focus-to-an-nsbutton))

Comment: @Meriw: what do you mean by "focused when it opens?" If you mean that the title bar is grey and the upper left resize/close buttons are colored, then yes. But I wonder if there is a different kind of focus for the window that I'm missing.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant. That was my last guess :/ Did you try using the code I posted to set the first responder?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120994/discussion-between-dribbler-and-meriw).